# React accessing state from a dynamically generated form, multiple levels deep

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The state of this form consists of three levels: A > B > C

```
A: [
            {
                name: "foo",
                ...
                B: [
                    {
                        name: "bar",
                        ...
                        C:[
                            {
                                name: "baz",
                                ...
                            },
                            {
                                name: "bat":,
                                ...
                            }
                        ]
                    },
               ]
            },
            ...
]
```

Basically, there needs to be an input field for each name attribute in three resources that are children of each other.

```
 <div className="subvariation-tree">
                {
                this.state.A.map( (a, aIdx) =>
                    <div key={aIdx}>
                        <input type="text"
                            value={this.state.A[aIdx].name}
                            onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                            {
                            a.B.map( (b, bIdx)  =>
                                <div key={bIdx}>
                                    <input type="text"
                                        value={this.state.A[aIdx].B[bIdx].name}
                                        onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                                        {
                                        b.C.map( (c, cIdx) =>
                                            <div key={cIdx} >
                                                <input type="text"
                                                    value={this.state.A[aIdx].B[bIdx].C[cIdx]}
                                                    onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                                            </div>
                                        )
                                        }
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            )
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
                }
            </div>
```

Problem is, I guess it seems obvious but I'm not able to access aIdx for example within the loop for the C attribute.

Is there any way around this? Is this a ridiculous design? A ridiculous use case for React? I am struggling pretty badly with this idea. I think I could manage it in vanilla JavaScript but I am trying to learn React.

Comment: I'm trying better understand the question - Why you need an input field for the name attribute?

Comment: Thanks! So, these are 'variations' and 'subvariationcategories' and 'subvariations' that are used to create different 'versions' of products for an ecommerce mockup. So let's say the Product is a shirt, then the first level variation might be for color: [red, white, blue, etc.] and then those need subCategories, say Size, which then need variations of their own, say [s, m, l, xl, etc.] -- and I'm stopping it at 2 levels, but this seems like a pretty standard ecommerce feature so I need to represent it somehow. I'm very confused by it though T_T

Comment: The user of this 'product variation management dashboard' needs to be able to add different variations, essentially as many as they want/need.

Comment: Isn't `this.state.A[aIdx].B[bIdx].name` the same as `b.name` ? You are the same iteration in your A and B at that point. (_same for `a.name` and `c.name`_).

Comment: btw you should have access to the `aIdx` in the `C` loop. Are you sure the problem is not the missing `.name` at the end ?

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli thanks that was indeed part of the problem. Sorry for the lack of info on the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply write in like

```html
<div className="subvariation-tree">
{
  this.state.A.map( (a, aIdx) => {
    return <div key={aIdx}>
            <input type="text" value={a.name} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
             {
                a.B.map( (b, bIdx)  => {
                  return <div key={bIdx}>
                           <input type="text" value={b.name} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                           {
                              b.C.map( (c, cIdx) => {
                                return <div key={cIdx} >
                                         <input type="text" value={c.name} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                                        </div>
                              })
                            }
                          </div>
                })
               }
           </div>
  })
}
</div>
```

Comment: So the parameters of `map` will keep a reference to the original state? I would have thought that map makes a copy, so as you update b in the state, you would lose connection

Comment: Your this.state.A will be changed if anything inside it is changed whether  it is B or C, whole object will be eligible for re rendering. React based on its diff mechanism will update the dom.

Answer (score 1):

You should actually have access to the `aIdx` in the loop for the `C`.

If the problem is that it shows `[object Object]` in the input it is because you have ommited the `.name` for the `C` elements.

So instead of

```
value={this.state.A[aIdx].B[bIdx].C[cIdx]}
```

use

```
value={this.state.A[aIdx].B[bIdx].C[cIdx].name}
```

But as [Sakshi Nagpal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49532210/128165) mentions you could have used `a.name`, `b.name` and `c.name` directly since you have a local variable for the iterated object.

Here is a demo with both approaches: https://codesandbox.io/s/mz82r16o8p

Comment: The problem is the value isn't reflect changes to the state, making it an essentially useless form. Should it be working like this? Or is it essentially impossible to keep track of a multi-tiered, dynamic form in React?

Comment: Ack nvm, it was once again my own mistake.